# If $f:A→\Bbb R^n$ is differentiable at $a$ then there exist $δ>0$ such that $\Biggl|\frac{f(a+tu)-f(a)-B\cdot tu}{|t|}\Biggl|<ε$ for any $t\in(-δ,δ)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

> **Definition**
>
> Let $A\subset\Bbb R^m$ and let $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ a function and we suppose that $A$ contains a neighborhood of $a$. So given $u\in\Bbb R^m$ with $u\neq 0$ we define the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ with respect to the vector $u$ the quantity
> $$
> f'(a;u):=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+tu)-f(a)}t
> $$
> provided the limit exists.
>
> **Definition**
>
> Let $A\subset\Bbb R^m$ and let $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ a function and we suppose $A$ contains a neighborhood of $a$. So we say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if there is a $n$ by $m$ matrix $B$ such that
> $$
> \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B\cdot h}{|h|}\rightarrow0\,\,\,\text{as}\,\,\,h\rightarrow0
> $$
> The matrix $B$, which is unique, is called the derivative of $f$ at $a$; t is denoted $Df(a)$.
>
> **Theorem**
>
> Let $A\subset\Bbb R^m$ and let $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ a function. So if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then all the directionalderivatives of $f$ at $a$ exists and
> $$
> f'(a;u)=Df(a)\cdot u
> $$
>
> *Proof*. See the theorem $5.1$ of the text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres.

So clearly with the previous definition if $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ is derivable at the point $a$ in the direction $u\in\Bbb R^n$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta_{\epsilon,u}$ such that
$$
\Biggl|\frac{f(a+tu)-f(a)}t\Biggl|<\epsilon
$$
for any $t\in(-\delta_{\epsilon,u},\delta_{\epsilon,u})$ and so for the completness theorem given $\epsilon>0$ the quantity
$$
\delta_\epsilon:=\inf\{\delta_{\epsilon,u}\in\Bbb R^n: u\,\text{is a direction of}\,\Bbb R^n\}
$$
is well defined and it is non negative. So I ask if in the case where $f$ is differentiable at $a$ necessarly it must be $\delta_\epsilon>0$ for any $\epsilon>0$

So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X\subset\Bbb R^m$ and let $f:X\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ a differentiable function at $x_0$. So we define the function $\tilde f:Y\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ through the condition
$$
\tilde f(h):=\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-Df(x_0)\cdot h}{|h|}
$$
where $B$ is a neighborhood of $0$ such that if $h\in Y$ then $(x_0+h)\in X$. So by your definition we have
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\tilde f(h)=0
$$
that is for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|\tilde f(h)|<\epsilon
$$
for any $h\in B(0,\delta)$. Now $h\in B(0,\delta)$ if and only if $|h|<\delta$ and since for any $h\in\Bbb R^n$ there exist a scalar $t\in\Bbb R$ and a direction $ u\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $h=tu$ then $\tilde f(h)=\tilde f(tu)$ and so we can reformulate what above saying that
$$
\Biggl|\frac{f(x_0+tu)-f(x_0)-Df(x_0)\cdot h}{|t|}\Biggl|<\epsilon
$$
for any $t\in(-\delta,\delta)$ and for **any** $u\in\Bbb R^n$ and so what you state follows immediately.